# LCM for Pochhammer symbols

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

For $x\in\mathbb C$ and $n\in\mathbb N_0$, one defines the Pochhammer symbol $(x,n)$ by $(x,n)=\frac{\Gamma(x+n)}{\Gamma(n)}=x(x+1)\cdots(x+n-1)$. For $\alpha\in\overline{\mathbb Q}\setminus\mathbb Z^-_0$ and $k$ a positive integer, can one determine an (optimal?) bound for the least positive integer $m_k$ (depending on $n$ obviously) such that all the $m_k\frac1{(\alpha,n-j)^j}$ ($0\le j\le k$) belong to $O_{\alpha}$, the ring of integers of the field $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: What does $\mathbb Z^-_0$ mean?

Comment: the non-positive integers.